# Saving to watchOS 2 document folder

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2

My iOS app sends a database to `WatchKit (watchOS 2)`. In `WatchKit` i use the following code to get the watch document folder to save the new file in:

```
NSURL* fileURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDatabase.sqlite"];
```

This results in an URL:

```
@"file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/47E13085-9030-4ED2-906F-01CBA323F07A/Documents/MyDatabase.sqlite"
```

However, when I call the function:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] replaceItemAtURL:fileURL withItemAtURL:url backupItemName:nil options:0 resultingItemURL:nil error:&error];
```

It throws an error saying:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “MyDatabase.sqlite” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents”."
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “MyDatabase.sqlite”

How can I find a folder I'm allowed to save to?
Naturally this code worked fine in the simulator so I assume I'm missing something not too obvious.

BR
Frederik

Comment: You shouldn't move Core Data files with NSFileManager use NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for that. Moving the file with NSFileManager might corrupt your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is that apple watch extensions can't save files to their documents dir. I was able to save files by using app Groups. Add an app group to your entitlements and then you should be able to write to the following dir:

```
let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.my.cool.watch.app")
```

Comment: This does not work in >= iOS 11. Use something like `FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first` instead.